# Which is the best Visual Slam algorithm to implement using stereo vision? Are there any source code available?

Tags: stereo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to implement visual SLAM using stereo camera in C/C++. I found papers on SLAM using Laser scanners and also cameras, but they are for robots. I need it for cars.Please let me know which algo to implement or are there any source code available?I know programming in C/C++ and also OpenCV. Suggest me how to start.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241872/which-is-the-best-visual-slam-algorithm-to-implement-using-stereo-vision?-are-there-any-source-code-available?/) by [Vijeet](https://answers.ros.org/users/27772/vijeet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-08-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are many open source algorithms using visual SLAM. Use [this link](https://openslam.org/) to check for a few implementation. I am not sure what you mean by applying it for cars, theoretically they should work if you are using stereo vision to get data, be it robots or cars.

I would suggest starting with [ORB-SLAM](http://webdiis.unizar.es/%7Eraulmur/orbslam/), [Open RatSLAM](https://openslam.org/openratslam.html) and [OKVIS](https://github.com/ethz-asl/okvis) since they seem to provide better results in most cases. You can of course try other algorithms for comparing the performance. Some of the algorithms may be for monocular camera but later might release a version for stereo camera, so look out for that. Other algorithms that may be interesting based on your question would be [LSD SLAM](https://github.com/tum-vision/lsd_slam), [LibViso](https://github.com/OpenMORA/vision-pkg/tree/master/StereoOdometry_libviso/libviso), [PTAM](https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_ptam) to list a few. You also mentioned finding some papers on the related topic, it is quite likely that they already have some kind of implementation in place to take a look at.

Also if you are looking for data with cars, [KITTI dataset](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/raw_data.php) seems to be quite popular.

With my limited experience I would say there is not yet best algorithm which can be identified.

---

Originally posted by [apoorv98](https://answers.ros.org/users/28215/apoorv98/) with karma: 36 on 2016-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vijeet](https://answers.ros.org/users/27772/vijeet/) on 2017-05-23**:
Thanks for the information. Its really helpful.

**Comment by [sunt40](https://answers.ros.org/users/40158/sunt40/) on 2019-02-23**:
Could you please tell me how to run openratslam in ubuntu16.04 with ROSkinetic and opencv3.4 ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Another very interesting algorithm is RTAB: https://introlab.github.io/rtabmap/ . It is available as a ROS package, wtih an active developer and seems to produce quite impressive dense maps.

---

Originally posted by [sihe](https://answers.ros.org/users/30331/sihe/) with karma: 60 on 2017-05-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1